# Random CountDownTimer Loop

Tags: android

I played a little around with CountDownTimer. However, for a special app I need the following functionality:

1. Start CountDownTimer with random runtime
2. Beep when finished
3. Wait 5 Seconds
4. Beep again
   GOTO 1.

This procedure should be startet with a button and should also be canceled with a button. I found post here with a looped CountDownTimer, but this doesn't work with random runtime.

Comment: for coutdown timer start here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not going to give you the code. That's your homework. I will however explain how the `countDownTimer` will work.

Once you've set up the CDT class create a new object.

```
private static myCDT newTime;//static makes sure there's only one instance of the variable in the entire program
newTime = new myCDT(randNum*1000, 1000);
```

Say randNum is 10, then the count down is for 10 seconds.

To generate the random number find out what you want the max limit to be. I'm assuming it to be 50. So the CDT will have an option from 0-50s.

`int randNum=50*Math.random();`

If you want to exclude 0 and want the minimum to be `1s`

`int randNum=1+49*Math.random();`

Now also set a boolean variable for the button. The first time it's clicked let it be set to true. Use this variable as the condition in a while. Now, if the user clicks the button again, set the variable to false. Call the `cancel()` function for your CDT object `newTime`.  Now call `onFinish()` function for your CDT. This will bring back flow of control to the while loop, the condition will now be false and so the loop stops. Make sure this loop is in the click listener function of the button. Or in any other function but be sure to call it from the click listener.